# Updating Top for chunks

Tags: sql, sql-update, iteration, sql-server-2016

We have a loop to update a table with several million rows in chunks.

Currently we are testing with chunks of 50K, but some of the iterations actually update a bit less than that (E.g. 49983).

This is the general structure of the loop that we're using:

```
WHILE @Row<=@loop
BEGIN
    update top (50000) MR
    set mr.Id_P = mp.PKey
    from DWH.[MResults] MR join DWH.MappingP MP
    on MR.P_Root=MP.Id_Root and MR.P_Ext=MP.Id_Ext
    and MR.id_p is null

set @Row=@Row+1
END
```

Shouldn't each iteration affect 50K rows? What is causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and add the SQL server you're using?

Comment: I think this might occur if your `join` has multiple matches on the table being updated.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, almost sure that we are encountering multiple matches in this query. Can you explain how this affects the outcome?
Thanks!

Comment: @Gidil . . . 500,000 results from the `FROM` are chosen for the update, but these represent fewer than 500,000 rows.